# SVM margin equations

Tags: mathematical-statistics, svm

The equation of a margin in SVM is $\frac{2}{\lVert \mathbf{w} \rVert}$, which I completely understand.

It is also rewritten as $\frac{1}{2} \lVert \mathbf{w} \rVert^2$ for the sake of mathematical convenience or "convention".

However, I do not see how these two equations are equivalent. I understand it works but I just don't see it and it's bothering me. Could anyone please help me with the mathematical proof that they're equivalent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The point is that $\arg\max_w \frac{2}{||w||} = \arg\min_w \frac{||w||^2}{2}$ - in other words maximizing the margin is equivalent to minimizing the norm in terms of the solution.

Comment: I finally understood this a week or so after posting it here. Turns out watching lectures at a 2x speed isn't always the best thing to do! Thank you!